# Filter the Buddypress bp_core_signup_user

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I want to send out a e-mail to the site admin that a new Buddypress user has signed up. That is what the first function is for. It works great. The second function is to append a few xprofile custom fields into the e-mail. Sadly the filter in the 2e function is not working. How can I make it work? Or how can I combine them so that they work?

```
function my_pending( $user_id, $user_login, $user_password, $user_email, $usermeta ) {
// Send the email notification.
wp_mail( 'some@some.com', $user_login . ' bla bla', 'bla bla' );
}
add_action( 'bp_core_signup_user', 'my_pending', 10, 5 );
```

And the second function:

```
function custom_activation_email_body( $message, $user_id, $key  ) {

$field1 = xprofile_get_field_data( '11', $user_id );
$field2 = xprofile_get_field_data( '12', $user_id );
$field3 = xprofile_get_field_data( '4', $user_id );

$message .= sprintf( __( "Username: %s Email: %s Membership Type: %s", 'lang' ), $field1,   $field2, $field3 );

return $message;

}
add_filter('bp_core_signup_user', 'custom_activation_email_body', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a field id, don't use it as a string, so

```
xprofile_get_field_data( '11', $user_id );
```

should be

```
xprofile_get_field_data( 11, $user_id );
```

And I think your filter is applied to the email sent to the new user. 
So move your xprofile calls into the add_action function. 
Review [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) to see how to setup the fields.

Comment: Thanks shanebp. The string part is clear to me now. I changed that. but the xprofile calls into the add_action function I don't understand. Could you please point me in the right direction. I read the wp_mail part but I'm stuck :-(